# Excel vba : assign all properties to a cell from an array of range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

My goal is to save a Cell and all its properties and value in an array of range, and then write back all properties and values of this cell to another cell from the array (like a copy paste function but pasting from the array).

Here is a simple test procedure :

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Range_Grid(1) As Range
    Dim CellAdress As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set Range_Grid(1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 1) = Range_Grid(1)
End Sub
```

So here in the first element of the array Range_Grid(1), I really get the full range saved and I can access every property the original range ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3) had, like font style, format, color, comment, etc..

But when I try to write this range from array to another empty cell, it only write the value...

Any idea how to write all the properties from the array like if it was a copy/paste from sheet to sheet?

Comment: try: `Range_Grid(1).Copy ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 1)`

Comment: Thanks it works in a way.
But I've just realized that the range saved in the array is not really saved as independant entity, I mean that it seems to be a pointer to the cell on the sheet. So if after the line Set Range_Grid(1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3), I go manually change the value and property of this cell on the sheet to get an empty cell, then the Range_Grid(1).Copy ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 1) leaves the cell(4,1) empty too...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of moving all of the formatting from a range in an array back into excel at once. This leaves you with two options: either you copy within excel as Scott Craner suggested, or you copy each type of formatting individually. For example, if you wanted to copy the value (which is the default and hence is what is copied in your original code) and the cell background colour, then you could use the following code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Range_Grid(1) As Range

    Set Range_Grid(1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 1) = Range_Grid(1)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = Range_Grid(1).Interior.ColorIndex
End Sub
```

Unfortunately there are probably over a dozen types of formatting that you may want to deal with at any given time...

Comment: Thanks. I've already written a whole function based on saving separated parts of the properties to retrieve them when I need to. So I was searching for a full property solution. I guess there is not really solutions as I've red a lot of forum on this subject and people always says they thought there wasn't really a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's an alternative: use Copy and PasteSpecial functions.

```
Sub Test()

    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3).Copy
    ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 1).PasteSpecial(xlPasteAll)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. But in fact here you just copy/paste from the sheet to the sheet. My goal was to saved a grid from a sheet into an array, and later, whatever has been done one the original sheet, "paste back" from the array to the sheet. It's about dealing to manage an engine for undo-redo function, because the undo stack is automatically erased by Excel when something is written on the sheet by the code...
So I've already created an engine that works fine just for a few properties like value, text, color...but it works by saving properties individually.